Questions to the code of the package aligned-overset
The package aligned-overset redefines \overset and \underset from amsmath in order to use the base character as alignment position in aligned math environments. Here is the package code:
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% aligned-overset.dtx  (with options: `package')
%% 
%% Copyright (C) 2018 by Marcel Krueger
%%
%% This file may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
%% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any later
%% version. The latest version of this license is in:
%%
%% http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%%
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of
%% LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage
  {aligned-overset}
  {2018/04/04}
  {0.1.0}
  {aligned overset and underset}

\RequirePackage{xparse,amsmath,mathtools}
\box_new:N\l__alignedsets_clap_box
\box_new:N\l__alignedsets_full_box

\let\__alignedsets_original_overset:nn\overset
\cs_set:Npn\overset{
  \group_align_safe_begin:
  \__alignedsets_modified_overset:nwn
}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\__alignedsets_modified_overset:nwn{mt{&}m}{
  \group_align_safe_end:
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}{
    \group_begin:
    \hbox_set:Nn\l__alignedsets_clap_box{
      $
      \displaystyle
      {}\__alignedsets_original_overset:nn{\mathclap{#1}}{#3}{}
      $
    }
    \hbox_set:Nn\l__alignedsets_full_box{
      $
      \displaystyle
      {}\__alignedsets_original_overset:nn{#1}{#3}{}
      $
    }
    \hspace{
      \dim_eval:n{(\box_wd:N\l__alignedsets_full_box-\box_wd:N\l__alignedsets_clap_box)/2}
    }
    \exp_args:NNNx
        \group_end:
        {&}
        \hspace{
          -\dim_eval:n{
            (\box_wd:N\l__alignedsets_full_box-\box_wd:N\l__alignedsets_clap_box)/2
          }
        }
    \__alignedsets_original_overset:nn{#1}{#3}
  }{
    \__alignedsets_original_overset:nn{#1}{#3}
  }
}
\let\__alignedsets_original_underset:nn\underset
\cs_set:Npn\underset{
  \group_align_safe_begin:
  \__alignedsets_modified_underset:nwn
}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\__alignedsets_modified_underset:nwn{mt{&}m}{
  \group_align_safe_end:
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}{
    \group_begin:
    \hbox_set:Nn\l__alignedsets_clap_box{
      $
      \displaystyle
      {}\__alignedsets_original_underset:nn{\mathclap{#1}}{#3}{}
      \m@th
      $
    }
    \hbox_set:Nn\l__alignedsets_full_box{
      $
      \displaystyle
      {}\__alignedsets_original_underset:nn{#1}{#3}{}
      \m@th
      $
    }
    \hspace{
      \dim_eval:n{(\box_wd:N\l__alignedsets_full_box-\box_wd:N\l__alignedsets_clap_box)/2}
    }
    \exp_args:NNNx
        \group_end:
        {&}
        \hspace{
          -\dim_eval:n{
            (\box_wd:N\l__alignedsets_full_box-\box_wd:N\l__alignedsets_clap_box)/2
          }
        }
    \__alignedsets_original_underset:nn{#1}{#3}
  }{
    \__alignedsets_original_underset:nn{#1}{#3}
  }
}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `aligned-overset.sty'.

My questions are:

What is the purpose of \group_align_safe_begin:? It gets immediately closed in \alignedsets_modified_overset:nwn. Is it perhaps because of the possible & in the argument list? Unfortunately, it is not clear to me from documentation interface3.pdf.
Why is it necessary to wrap the part before the & in \begingroup and \endgroup?
Why is \mathsurround=0pt (via \m@th) used in the modified \underset but not in the modified \overset?
Are the empty groups before and after \__alignedsets_original_overset:nn{\mathclap{#1}}{#3} used to introduce ordinary atoms?

I hope these are not to many or stupid questions.
